# All combinations of alphanumeric string, better way?

Tags: java, string, recursion

The input to the "alphaNumeric" function is a String which consists of alphanumeric characters that are all lower case, for example "hello123hello". I want to be able to check all upper/lower case letter combinations for this string through a check( ) function. (Eg. HeLlO123hELlo is one of the combinations to be checked). I have written code in Java to do this where I store the matching String into an ArrayList, but would like to know if there a better way to do this without the ArrayList. Also, am I correct in saying the worst case runtime of this is O(2^n)? Note: Check is a function that returns either true or false, depending on whether the correct String is passed to the function.

```
public static String alphaNumeric(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    alphaHelper(input, "", list);
    return list.get(0);
}

private static void alphaHelper(String in, String current, ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (in.length() == 0) {
        if (check(current)) {
            list.add(current);
        }
    } else if (Character.isLetter(in.charAt(0))) {
        alphaHelper(in.substring(1),current+in.substring(0,1).toLowerCase(),list);
        alphaHelper(in.substring(1),current+in.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(),list);
    } else if (Character.isDigit(in.charAt(0))) {
        alphaHelper(in.substring(1),current+in.substring(0,1),list);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you basically saying you are checking whether all alphabetic characters are lower case?

Comment: Is there only one correct string?

Comment: yes, there is only one correct string, hence I don't see the ArrayList as a good option here

Comment: also, you're checking substrings like `"hel"`, `"hell"` etc. - do you need to check substrings like this or is it just a side-effect of your algorithm?

Comment: did you choose a password and now you can't remember what weird capitalization you used and you're trying to crack it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the `ArrayList` without changing your basic algorithm, you can do this:

```
public static String alphaNumeric(String input) {
    return alphaHelper(input, "");
}

private static String alphaHelper(String in, String current) {
    String result = null;

    if (check(current)) {
        result = current;
    } else if (Character.isLetter(in.charAt(0))) {
        result = alphaHelper(in.substring(1),current+in.substring(0,1).toLowerCase());
        if (result == null) result = alphaHelper(in.substring(1),current+in.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
    } else if (Character.isDigit(in.charAt(0))) {
        result = alphaHelper(in.substring(1),current+in.substring(0,1));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Yes it is O(2^n), and I can't see offhand how you would improve on that if you can't get the original string directly.

If you don't need to check substrings (i.e. you only care about case variations of the entire string) you could improve the algorithm by not testing the substrings, but it would still be O(2^n).

Comment: Why is the complexity O(2^n)?

Comment: Because worst case you have to try each character in upper and lower case variants. So 2^n operations

Comment: Welcome. Of course I could still be wrong in my interpretation :-)

Comment: Thanks @CupawnTae. That was great :)

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily set both the check and input to lowercase and compare them then.

```
    public static boolean alphaNumeric(String input, String check) {
        return input.toLowerCase().equals(check.toLowerCase());
    }
```

-Sean